# bootstrap stepy tabs not working in html begin form() - mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working on a view where user enters his/her information in step....

Step are actually tabs you all know...

> I am posting data to action, so i need to wrap all html code in
>   Html.Beginform()...but wrapped code consists tabs which not works in
>   html.beginform()
>
> When i remove the Html.Beginform, the tabs work fine.....

My html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <section id="main-content">
            <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
                <!-- page start-->
                <div class="row">
     <section class="panel">
    <header class="panel-heading">
        Registration
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="stepy-tab">
            <ul id="default-titles" class="stepy-titles clearfix">
                <li id="default-title-0" class="current-step">
                    <div>Step 1</div>
                </li>
                <li id="default-title-1" class="disabled">
                    <div>Step 2</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="default" name="myform">
            <fieldset title="Step1" class="step" id="default-step-0">
                <legend> </legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset title="Step 2" class="step" id="default-step-1">
                <legend> </legend>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Card Key</label>
           <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CardKey" name="CardKey">
            </div>
           </div>
            </fieldset>
          <input type="submit" class="finish" value="Save" id="Free" />
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
                    </div>
                <!-- page end-->
            </section>
        </section>
```

Js function

```
<script>
    //step wizard
    $(function () {
        $('#default').stepy({
            backLabel: 'Previous',
            block: true,
            nextLabel: 'Next',
            titleClick: true,
            titleTarget: '.stepy-tab'
        });
    });
</script>
```

What can be probable causes, please if someone help....any kind of help or reference will be appreciated.....thanks for your time

Comment: Any console errors you are getting? what plugin is that?? Any links to that?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks for reply, its jquery wizzard plugin stepy i am using

Comment: Did you get any console errors?

Comment: surprisingly i doesnt have console error except nicescroll.js.....

Comment: can you provide the link for the plugin?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Wizard-Plugin-Stepy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are creating a `form` inside `form`!! I hope you know that `Html.BeginForm` will create one more `form` and inside that you are placing one more `form` for stepy. **[Nesting Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)** are not allowed in HTML. I don't think you need `form` at top where you've written `@Html.BeginForm` instead you can use the same below where your other `form` exists like one below:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("actionname","controllername",FormMethod.Post,new{@class="form-horizontal",id="default",name="myform"}))
{ 
   <fieldset title="Step1" class="step" id="default-step-0">
      <legend> </legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name">
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset title="Step 2" class="step" id="default-step-1">
      <legend> </legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Card Key</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CardKey" name="CardKey">
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" class="finish" value="Save" id="Free" />
}
```

The above `Html.BeginForm` helper will create the below code

```
<form action="/cname/ac" class="form-horizontal" id="default" method="post" name="myform">
```

I am assuming that you only need only steps data to post and believe me above approach works!

Comment: thanks for answer, yes i realized, although i have solved this tye of problem before, i am doing this mistake again and again, +1 for effort and accept...you are the man...cheers